# How to rename file within a partition in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I have a date partitioned data in hive. However the file within a certain partition has a name like 000112_0. Is there a way to rename this file

Comment: Why do you want to rename and what the name should be?

Comment: Since it is the file under partition , I think you can simply rename the file using hdfs dfs -mv command

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration property to do this but you can write your custom reducer class like `OutputFormat` to achieve this.

`OutputFormat` describes the output-specification for a Map-Reduce job.
The Map-Reduce framework relies on the OutputFormat of the job to:

- Validate the output-specification of the job. For e.g. check that the output directory doesn't already exist.
- Provide the `RecordWriter` implementation to be used to write out the output files of the job. Output files are stored in a `FileSystem`.

Answer (score 0):

You can. Run:

```
hadoop fs -mv /path_to_file/old_name /path_to_file/new_name
```

Comment: I used exactly like that to accomplish the task. Thanks for the feedback